# $.ajax not functioning correctly - returns index.html

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to write a function that allows me to stop writing redundant ajax requests on each form and element that I want to use it with. It's a pretty simple concept but I can't seem to figure out what's wrong with it. I only get one error but it has to do with a bad token because the json isn't valid but if I remove the json functions, it does nothing. If I populate a container with the returned data, I just get a copy of the index page. This is being run from the index page if that makes a difference.

I'm just curious if anyone see's any errors that I'm missing here...

Thanks!

Here's the code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
/* ajax request standard functions 
    Optional attributes:
        loadtype[html]: prepend, append, html(*complete page load*)
        ajaxcon[error]: container to be affected by ajax
        method[GET]: post/get
        loader[progress1]: alternate load image other than the standard 

*/
$(document).on('click', '.ajaxMe', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var el = $(this); //a, li, form
    var tag = el.prop('tagName'); //a, li, form
        if(tag == 'FORM'){aType = 1;}else{aType = 2;} //sets default to a/li
    var method = el.attr('method');
        if(!method) method = 'GET'; //default method
    var ajaxcon = el.attr('ajaxcon');
        //if there's no ajax container to receive the data, return an error 
        if(!ajaxcon && aType != 1){
            //later on, this should call a function that pops up the error box instead of an alert
            alert("There seems to be a code error. Please contact support or try again later");
            return false;
        }
    var loadtype = el.attr('loadtype');
        if(!loadtype) loadtype = 'html'; //default loadtype set to html
    var altloader = el.attr('altloader');
        if(!altloader) altloader = 'http://localhost/mgo/img/gifs/loader.gif'; //default wait image

    //set the variables that are determined by the parent element type
    if(aType == 1){
        var href = el.attr('action');
        var sdata = el.serialize(); //We can serialize the data of all forms without checking because checking is going to be done on the php side from now on
    }else if(aType == 2){
        var href = el.attr('href');
        var sdata = el.attr('rel');
    }

    /*JSON return layout:
        return{
            status: 0/1 -- included in case there is additional checking on the jquery side before/instead php redirect
            message: message to display if bad
            badInputs: inputs to highlight
        }
    */

    alert(sdata);
    $.ajax({
        type: method,
        URL: href,
        data: sdata,
        success: function(ret){ //return is always going to be JSON
            if(aType == 1){
                //if data gets returned, it's an error. if no error, the php takes over and forces the next page
                var r = $.parseJSON(ret);
                el.find('.TopMsg')[loadtype](r.message);
            }else if(aType == 2){
                ajaxcon[loadtype](ret);
            }
        }
    });
});
});
```

**EDIT**
For good measure, I'm adding the html and the php

**HTML**

```
<form class = 'Frm-cb ajaxMe' id = 'frmsignup' action = 'http://localhost/mgo/modules/signup/php/signup1.php'>
<h1 style = 'background-color: green;'>Sign up now for all the benefits of MGo!</h1>

    <div class = 'TopMsg'></div>

    <label>email</label>
    <input type = 'text' name = 'email' id = 'email'>

    <label>confirm email</label>
    <input type = 'text' name = 'email2' id = 'email2'>

    <label>password</label>
    <input type = 'password' name = 'password' id = 'password'>

    <label>confirm password</label>
    <input type = 'password' name = 'password2' id = 'password2'>

    <label>zip code</label>
    <input type = 'text' name = 'zip' id = 'zip' maxlength = '5'>

    <button type = 'submit'>finish</button>
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?

/*
    This script is going to do the data validation for the jQuery so users can't hard code the scripts to change validation rules.
    The output is JSON. 
        JSON output map:
        [return]
            [status]
            [badInputs]
                [inputname]
            [msg]
            [addClass]
            [changeClass]
*/

include_once "C:/xampp/htdocs/mgo/scripts/php/connect/gen_user_db_connect.php";
include_once "C:/xampp/htdocs/mgo/scripts/php/validate/dataValidation.php";

$bi = array();
$msg  = "";
$stat = 1;

$e1 = $_GET['email'];
$e2 = $_GET['email2'];
$p1 = $_GET['password'];
$p2 = $_GET['password2'];
$zip = $_GET['zip'];

$inputs = array("0", "username", "text");

$eChk = validate($e1)['email'];
$pChk = validate($p1)['len'];
$zChk = validate($zip);

if($eChk == 0){
    $msg .= "Please enter a valid email address\n";
    array_push($bi, "#email");
    $stat = 0;
}

if($e1 != $e2){
    $msg .= "Emails don't match\n";
    array_push($bi, "#email2");
    $stat = 0;
}

if($pChk < 6){
    $msg .= "Password must be a minimum of 6 characters\n";
    array_push($bi, "#password");
    $stat = 0;
}

if($p1 != $p2){
    $msg .= "Passwords don't match\n";
    array_push($bi, "#password2");
    $stat = 0;
}

if($zChk['num'] == 0){
    $msg .= "Must enter a valid zip code\n";
    $stat = 0;
}

$return = json_encode(array("msg" => "<pre>$msg</pre>",
                           "status" => $stat,
                           "badInputs" => $inputs));

echo $return;
?>
```

Comment: add exit; at the end of file in your ajaxcall file. so it will break execution of your index file

Comment: put your html code here so i will find the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the URL parameter should not be capitalized -- "url" not "URL".

Comment: Well I feel like an idiot but that's an awesome catch. Fixed it right up. Thank you! You're a life saver! I can't believe it was that simple.

Comment: I knew from the title that you had forgotten (or misspelled) the url parameter.  Perhaps it will make you feel better if you try to guess _how_ I knew what you did.

Comment: I have no idea how the title gave that away...please enlighten me

Comment: I knew that if you fail to supply a URL, the value will default to the empty string.  Since the URL is interpreted in the context of the current base, it will try to open the directory the current page was loaded from.  In that situation, most web-servers will return index.html.

I know all this because I have made the same mistake myself, several times.

Answer (score 0):

1. It seems quiet odd that you are doing frontent script validation(checking for tampering) on the server side, since if someone can tamper with the script then he can easily tamper the script data thats being sent, so no security here.
2. Try adding `dataType:json` to the ajax call.
3. Add `die();` to the end of your php script to terminate the execution any further.

So that should make your code as...

**JS**

```
....

alert(sdata);
$.ajax({
    type: method,
    URL: href,
    data: sdata,
    dataType:json,
    success: function(ret){ //return is always going to be JSON
....
```

**PHP**

```
....

$return = json_encode(array("msg" => "<pre>$msg</pre>",
                           "status" => $stat,
                           "badInputs" => $inputs));

echo $return;
die();
?>
```

Comment: Thank you. That's a good point. Just out of curiosity..how would you add more security? I have to get the data from a to b and no matter which side I check it on, it can be messed with. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Just treat all the data as hostile, blacklist all the data and only allow the data that you want, I am talking about strict (*verry strict*) input validation thats it. No need for checking if the frontend script has been tampered with.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thank you